# Identifier 'updates' is not defined. 'Changelog[]' does not contain such a member

Tags: angular, typescript

I've seen a lot a similar issues related to the one I have but can't point what's blocking here.

I have a Changelog Interface, changelog.ts :

```
export interface Changelog {
  number: string;
  updates: Updates[];
}

interface Updates {
  name: string;
  updatesContent: UpdatesContent[];
}

interface UpdatesContent {
  name: string;
  content: string;
}
```

This interface is called is a changelog.component.ts :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialogRef } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { Changelog } from 'src/app/_models/changelog';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-changelog',
  templateUrl: './changelog.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./changelog.component.scss'],
})
export class ChangelogComponent implements OnInit {
  versions: Changelog[] = [];

  constructor(private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<ChangelogComponent>) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.versions.push({
      number: 'test',
      updates: [
        {
          name: 'test',
          updatesContent: [
            {
              name: 'test',
              content: 'test',
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    });
  }

  closeChangelog() {
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }
}
```

The content is displayed in changelog.component.html :

```
<div *ngIf="versions">
    <div class="mb-5" *ngFor="let version of versions">
      <h2>Version {{ version.number }}</h2>

      <div *ngFor="let updates of versions.updates">
        <h5>{{ updates.name }}</h5>
        <ul>
          <li *ngFor="let update of updates.updatesContent">
            <strong>{{ update.name }} :</strong> {{ update.content }}
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I have the following error Identifier 'updates' is not defined. 'Changelog[]' does not contain such a member

Could you help me to point the issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Have you tried the following?***

1.Use ? before property

```
 <div *ngFor="let updates of version?.updates">
```

2.Use bracket notation [ ]

```
 <div *ngFor="let updates of version['updates']">
```

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-8jsrzj

Comment: With
  <div *ngFor="let updates of versions['updates']">
The error disappear but none content is shown

The first proposition still display the error

Comment: In second ngFor I think it should be ``let updates of version['updates']``

Comment: Still not content even though there isn't any error anymore

Comment: I have updated the solution with stackblitzz link. Check it out

Comment: Ahah, you were right I didn't see the second comment, I'm dumb, ty for pointing this out
versions instead of version...
Thank you very much